# How to make android 10 phone only use certain BSSID devices with the same SSID or at least ignore a specific BSSID?

Tags: wi-fi, networking, wifi-hotspot, android-10

I live in a hotel where all WiFi AccessPoints have the same SSID,
but the AP next to my room is not configured properly and no one bothers to call a technician. Since this faulty AP is closest, my Android phone keeps connecting to it as it has the strongest signal. Mind that I cannot physically disconnect/turn off the device as it belongs to the hotel.

On my Linux laptop I easily managed to connect to the next AP by setting the prefered BSSID.

Now I am trying to do the same with my Android 10 phone, but there aren't any similar settings.

I tried solving the issue by installing various Network utility apps, most of which were only logging all nearby AP hotspots and showing some specs like signal strength, some were showing the BSSIDs but couldn't make the phone connect to them.

Afterwards I thought if this approach is not possible maybe I could try to block the faulty AP's BSSID thus making sure I get connected to any other AP nearby. Alas I couldn't find any appropriate info for this as well.

I am sure there is a way. Maybe someone with the know-how could enlighten me.

Thank you!

Comment: If you can not disconnect the AP yourself go to the reception desk and demand that they disable the non-working AP.

Comment: Thank you @Robert for your comment. I know I tried, that's why I started to look for an alternative programmable way to do it. I begin to think that the good guys that develop Android OS don't want their users to be able to choose their connection that precisely.

Comment: did you ever find a way to do this on Android? i'm able to connect using BSSID on Windows & Linux, but not Android.

Comment: @Ridalgo no i didn't find any solution for Android. On Linux this is done very easy from the build in WiFi features, on Windows there are some free programs to download as well. For Android I tried many apps and settings with zero luck.